# find controls from emptydatatemplate in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

i am using EmptyDataTemplate for entering new data in grid while there is no existing data,but i am not able to find my controls in the EmptyDateTemplate

```
protected void gvNavigationDtls_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName.Equals("EInsert"))
        {
            GridViewRow emptyrow = gvNavigationDtls.Controls[0].Controls[0] as GridViewRow;
            if (((TextBox)emptyrow.FindControl("txtCode")).Text == "")
```

in page load also i checked by writing following code

```
gvNavigationDtls.DataBind();
            Control c = gvNavigationDtls.Controls[0].FindControl("txtCode");
            if (c != null)
            {
            }
```

but c is null,that means i am not able to find control to use it,
Please help,Thanks in Advance

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584913/asp-net-gridview-emptydatatemplate

Comment: http://aspdotnetcodebook.blogspot.in/2009/03/how-to-find-control-inside.html

Comment: Thank u very much i got the solution which you provided in 2nd comment it worked properly i followed each step n implemented it in my code,thank u very much Shekhar!!!

Answer (score 3):

```
protected void gvNavigationDtls_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName.Equals("EInsert"))
        {
          TextBox txtCode=(TextBox)gvNavigationDtls.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl("txtCode");
          txtCode.Text="Your value";
        }
     }
```

Comment: accessing emptydatarowcontrols. "Control[0].Controls[0]" refering the address of emptydatarow.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, just had this problem and it's really easy to find access the data but it's in the RowDataBound event.

```
    Protected Sub grdView(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles grdView.RowDataBound
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.EmptyDataRow Then
            Dim txt As TextBox = e.Row.FindControl("txtBox")
            txt.Text = "Hey, this works!"
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It is working!  I have tried so many ways, none of them was working.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the above code does not work.
I have to access the empty template and find the control like this:

```
TextBox tb1 = (TextBox)((System.Web.UI.Control)e.CommandSource).BindingContainer.Controls[0].FindControl("TextBox5");
```

The bindingcontainer of the "e.commandsource" is a gridviewrow (then, via the quickwatch you should find the container on which apply findcontrol by going deeper in the "controls" members)